# Read data from Teradata DB in Azure Spark

Tags: azure, apache-spark, teradata

I want to read and create a data frame of data from my Teradata Database, in azure spark. I have uploaded `terajdbc4.jar` in my spark cluster, and my code is as follows

```
val jdbcDF = sqlContext.load("jdbc", Map(
  "url" -> "jdbc:teradata://<server_name>, TMODE=TERA, user=my_user, password=*****",
  "dbtable" -> "schema.table_name",
  "driver" -> "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver"))
```

But I am getting errors as

> "Name or service not known at
> java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)".

My server name is `ecdwprod.na.ko.com`, which is correct, But I don't know why I am facing this issue. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Use `/` after the server name and before the first option, rather than `,`

Comment: Already tried /, but to no avail

Comment: What's the output of `nslookup ecdwprod.na.ko.com`?

Comment: "jdbc:teradata://ecdwprod.na.ko.com/TMODE=TERA, user=my_user, password=*****". This is the connection string I am providing, am I supposed to add anything extra ,or any correction ?

Comment: Should not have spaces in the url. And I'm not familiar with Azure Spark but this use of .load is long ago deprecated in favor of .read.format("jdbc").options(...).load()